# TensorFlow Word2Vec model running on GPU

Tags: python, word2vec, tensorflow, word-embedding

In [this TensorFlow example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb) a training of skip-gram Word2Vec model described. It contains the following code fragment, which explicitly requires CPU device for computations, i.e. `tf.device('/cpu:0')`:

```
batch_size = 128
embedding_size = 128  # Dimension of the embedding vector.
skip_window = 1  # How many words to consider left and right.
num_skips = 2  # How many times to reuse an input to generate a label.

# We pick a random validation set to sample nearest neighbors. Here we limit the
# validation samples to the words that have a low numeric ID, which by
# construction are also the most frequent. 
valid_size = 16  # Random set of words to evaluate similarity on.
valid_window = 100  # Only pick dev samples in the head of the distribution.
valid_examples = np.array(random.sample(range(valid_window), valid_size))
num_sampled = 64  # Number of negative examples to sample.

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # Input data.
    train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
    train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
    valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

    # Variables.
    embeddings = tf.Variable(
        tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
    softmax_weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                            stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
    softmax_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))

    # Model.
    # Look up embeddings for inputs.
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)

    # Compute the softmax loss, using a sample of the negative labels each time.
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights,
                                   biases=softmax_biases, inputs=embed,
                                   labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled,
                                   num_classes=vocabulary_size))

    # Optimizer.
    # Note: The optimizer will optimize the softmax_weights AND the embeddings.
    # This is because the embeddings are defined as a variable quantity and the
    # optimizer's `minimize` method will by default modify all variable quantities 
    # that contribute to the tensor it is passed.
    # See docs on `tf.train.Optimizer.minimize()` for more details.
    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)

    # Compute the similarity between minibatch examples and all embeddings.
    # We use the cosine distance:
    norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
    normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
    valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
    similarity = tf.matmul(valid_embeddings, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddings))
```

When trying switch to GPU, the following exception is raised:

> **InvalidArgumentError** (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation 'Variable_2/Adagrad': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.

I wonder what is the reason why the provided graph cannot be computed on GPU? Does it happen due to `tf.int32` type? Or should I switch to another optimizer? In other words, is there any way to make possible processing Word2Vec model on GPU? (Without types casting).

---

**UPDATE**

Following Akshay Agrawal recommendation, here is an updated fragment of the original code that achieves required result:

```
with graph.as_default(), tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    # Input data.
    train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
    train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
    valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

    embeddings = tf.Variable(
        tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
    softmax_weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                            stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
    softmax_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))    
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights,
                                       biases=softmax_biases,
                                       inputs=embed,
                                       labels=train_labels,
                                       num_sampled=num_sampled,
                                       num_classes=vocabulary_size))

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

    norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
    normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
    valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
    similarity = tf.matmul(valid_embeddings, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddings))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is raised because `AdagradOptimizer` does not have a GPU kernel for its sparse apply operation; a sparse apply is triggered because differentiating through the embedding lookup results in a sparse gradient.

`GradientDescentOptimizer` and `AdamOptimizer` do support sparse apply operations. If you were to switch to one of these optimizers, you would unfortunately see another error: tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss appears to create an op that does not have a GPU kernel. To get around that, you could wrap the `loss = tf.reduce_mean(...` line with a `with tf.device('/cpu:0'):` context, though doing so would introduce cpu-gpu communication overhead.

Comment: Ok, got it. So, basically, switch to optimizer which supports sparse operations _and_ compute loss on CPU, right?